# How to order on a filtered has many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, activerecord

I have `users` `locations` and a join table `visits`. Each user can visit multiple locations and i want a view of the users ordered by the name of the location of their most recent visit.

```
CREATE TABLE users
  ("id" int, "name" varchar(128))
;

CREATE TABLE locations
  ("id" int, "name" varchar(128))
;

CREATE TABLE visits
  ("id" int, "user_id" int, "location_id" int, "date" timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO users
    ("id", "name")
VALUES
    (1, 'Alpha'),
    (2, 'Bravo'),
    (3, 'Charlie');

INSERT INTO locations
    ("id", "name")
VALUES
    (4, 'Delta'),
    (5, 'Echo'),
    (6, 'Foxtrott');

INSERT INTO visits
  ("id", "user_id", "location_id", "date")
VALUES
  (1, 1, 4, '2000-02-03 00:00:00'),
  (2, 1, 5, '2000-02-02 00:00:00'),
  (3, 1, 6, '2000-02-01 00:00:00'),
  (4, 2, 6, '2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
  (5, 2, 5, '2000-01-01 00:00:00')
;
```

I hve tried

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, max(locations.name) as location_name, max(visits.date) as date
FROM users
LEFT JOIN visits ON users.id = visits.user_id
LEFT JOIN locations ON visits.location_id = locations.id
GROUP BY users.id, users.name
ORDER BY location_name
```

but max(locations.name) doesn't depend on max(visits.date)

another try is

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, t.date, locations.name as location_name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(date) as date, user_id
  FROM visits
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS t ON users.id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN visits on visits.date = t.date
LEFT JOIN locations on locations.id = visits.location_id
ORDER BY location_name
```

but this has problems when one user has two visits on the same date (i don't care which place gets chosen but it has to be only one)

the result should look something like this though date is not required.

```
id  name     date                  location_name
1   Alpha    2000-02-03T00:00:00Z  Delta
2   Bravo    2000-01-01T00:00:00Z  Echo
3   Charlie  (null)                (null)
```

the solution is preferably in ActiveRecord but plain sql is okay too

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ba2a6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will produce desired result.

I have populated your sample data in CTE.

Also there is no need of group by and aggregate functions like max. It does not require here.

```
      with users(id,name) as (
      select *
      from (
        values
        (1, 'Alpha'),
        (2, 'Bravo'),
        (3, 'Charlie')
      ) t
    ), locations(id,name) as (
      select *
      from(
        values
        (4, 'Delta'),
        (5, 'Echo'),
        (6, 'Foxtrott')
      ) t
    ), visits(id,user_id,location_id,date) as (
      select *
      from(
      VALUES
      (1, 1, 4, '2000-02-03 00:00:00'),
      (2, 1, 5, '2000-02-02 00:00:00'),
      (3, 1, 6, '2000-02-01 00:00:00'),
      (4, 2, 6, '2000-01-01 00:00:00'),
      (5, 2, 5, '2000-01-01 00:00:00')
      ) t
    ), res as (
    select
      distinct on(user_id)
      u.id as user_id,
      u.name,
      l.name as location_name,
      date
    from visits v
    join locations l on l.id=location_id
    right join users u on u.id=v.user_id
    order by user_id,date desc
   )
   select * from res order by location_name
```

Comment: Cool i didn't now `distinct on` exists this is indeed simpler.

Comment: i have been to quick to accept this. while this gives the right results they're not sortet by location_name. i guess wrapping it in `SELECT * FROM () AS t ORDER BY location_name` works but maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: I have edited my answer . Your above suggestion is obvious and simple. So we can go with it @Kaworu

Answer (score 0):

Little correction on groupings:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, max(locations.name) as location_name, visits.date as date
FROM users
LEFT JOIN visits ON users.id = visits.user_id
LEFT JOIN locations ON visits.location_id = locations.id
where visits.date = (select max(date) from visits where user_id = users.id)
GROUP BY users.id, users.name,visits.date
ORDER BY location_name
```

You can validate here that it gives correct results: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/24a0d/27

Answer (score 0):

Great job @Sabari:

I just composed a similar query and came here to see you have posted it already. This is basically the same query which only uses `LEFT JOIN`. I'm keeping it anyways.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) u.id
    ,u.name
    ,l.name
    ,DATE
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN visits v ON u.id = v.user_id 
LEFT JOIN locations l ON l.id = location_id
ORDER BY user_id
    ,DATE DESC
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/24a0d/39)